# Erroneous Snippet in Handlebars Tutorial?

Tags: handlebars.js

Is the example under the "Helpers" section of the Handlebars official tutorial (http://handlebarsjs.com/) erroneous? Because the snippet below does not work:

```
<ul>
  {{#each items}}
  <li>{{agree_button}}</li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

`agree_button` is supposed to be a helper function but there is nothing after it so I guess it is queried as a context variable, not a helper function.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's right you don't need to pass arguments to one helper, it can do repetitive code insertions that don't need any argument except the context itself.

Here is a fiddle that illustrate that it works like a charm https://jsfiddle.net/ChristopheThiry/y51b9caf/

```
<ul>
  {{#each items}}
  <li>{{agree_button}}</li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

Comment: I checked the fiddle but could not see anything rendered.

Comment: Yep I forgot to save my html, you may recheck